# Not pulling correct object out of ArrayList when called

Tags: android, arraylist, textview, inputstream, android-arrayadapter

I have a program that takes a stream of data in in the form of bytes. It then takes the bytes and makes strings out of the valid bytes. Then those strings are placed in an arraylist and called with view.setText(arraylistname.get(int index) of the arraylist class. Here is the code. messages is an ArrayList, position is the index, and readMessage is a string object.

```
 case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
           // rpmView.setText(readMessage);
            messages.add(readMessage);

            int position;       
            position = 0; //position < messages.size();){
            int position1;
            int position2;
            int position3;
            int position4;
            int position5;
                  rpmView.setText(messages.get(position));
                  position1 = position++;
                  tempView.setText(messages.get(position1));
                  position2 = position1++;
                  mphView.setText(messages.get(position2));
                  position3 = position2++;
                  gearView.setText(messages.get(position3));
                  position4 = position3++;
                  batteryVoltageView.setText(messages.get(position4));
                  position5 = position4++;
                  fuelLevelView.setText(messages.get(position5));
```

The problem is when the stream is read, all fields/views display the same info and don't update. Please help. I did a lot of research about listviews and arrayadapters, but i don't want a vertical scrolling list, I want textviews that update as the data changes, but the layout stays the same with the exception of the values changing.

Comment: Try displaying the messages.length, I think you are only adding a single element.

Comment: @Karan I only want one element at a time. What do you think of my followup questions?

Comment: Write a loop starting from 0 to messages.length and check the values present in the messages list. OR add the full code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the notifyDataSetChanged() over to the instance of the Adapter. Do this in a Handler

Comment: @ rohit mandiwal I am not using an Adapter. Do you think this is a problem for a dynamically changing array? I don't want to use listview, but I don't understand how to get a new view for each item that comes in from my data stream. When I tried to use an adapter it said I had to use a listview or spinner.

Comment: I am not using an Adapter. Do you think this is a problem for a dynamically changing array? I don't want to use listview, but I don't understand how to get a new view for each item that comes in from my data stream. When I tried to use an adapter it said I had to use a listview or spinner.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your use of the post-increment operator.

**This is happening:**

```
// Using the post-increment operator.    
int position = 0;
int position1, position2, position3;
position1 = position++; // position1 = 0, position = 1
position2 = position1++; // position2 = 0, position1 = 1
position3 = position2++; // position3 = 0, position2 = 1
```

**You might want this:**

```
// Using addition.    
int position = 0;
int position1, position2, position3;
position1 = position + 1; // position1 = 1, position = 0
position2 = position1 + 1; // position2 = 2, position1 = 1
position3 = position2 + 1; // position3 = 3, position2 = 2
```

**Or this:**

```
// Using the pre-increment operator.    
int position = 0;
int position1, position2, position3;
position1 = ++position; // position1 = 1, position = 1
position2 = ++position1; // position2 = 2, position1 = 2
position3 = ++position2; // position3 = 3, position2 = 3
```

Comment: @ Tim Mahoney thank you for your advice. It is still not working correctly. Do you think I need to call the setText methods outside the case block?

Comment: thank you for your advice. It is still not working correctly. Do you think I need to call the setText methods outside the case block?

Comment: The setText methods should work outside the case block. I would do as Karan says and output the data to LogCat.